# Spark Cluster has heartbeat timeouts and Yarn Scheduler

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have checked other related posts on Stackoverflow but none seems to relate directly with mine, as the spark version they referenced are over 5 years ago **and the spark version I am using is Spark 3.3.3**

I am running an Apache Spark Cluster with Yarn as the Master whilst using Jupyter Labs as the IDE. When I run the command to start the cluster it starts using:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import getpass
username = getpass.getuser()

spark = SparkSession. \
    builder. \
    config('spark.ui.port', '0'). \
    config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', f'/user/{username}/warehouse'). \
    enableHiveSupport(). \
    appName(f'{username} | Python - Kafka and Spark Integration'). \
    master('yarn'). \
    getOrCreate()
```

And the plan is to read stream from 24 json files in HDFS which are approximately 80MB each and then writestream while partitioning the data by three columns and storing them as **parquet** in another folder in HDFS.

This is the command I used:

```
file_df. \
    writeStream. \
    partitionBy('created_year', 'created_month', 'created_dayofmonth'). \
    format('parquet'). \
    option("checkpointLocation", f"/user/{username}/file_df/streaming/checkpoint/file_df"). \
    option("path", f"/user/{username}/file_df/streaming/data/files_parq"). \
    trigger(once=True). \
    start()
```

Then I get this output when I run it on my notebook

```
23/09/13 21:34:55 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.

<pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery at 0x7fd22851adc0>

[Stage 3:===============>                                          (5 + 2) / 19]

23/09/13 21:42:56 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 2 with no recent heartbeats: 120168 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
23/09/13 21:42:56 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on sparkde.camp.300123.internal: Executor heartbeat timed out after 120168 ms
23/09/13 21:42:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 41) (sparkde.camp.300123.internal executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 120168 ms

[Stage 3:===============>                                          (5 + 1) / 19]

23/09/13 21:42:58 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.172.0.3:41888
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

[Stage 3:========================>                                 (8 + 2) / 19]

23/09/13 21:45:55 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 3 on sparkde.camp.300123.internal: Container from a bad node: container_1694638458719_0001_01_000004 on host: sparkde.camp.300123.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-09-13 21:45:55.150]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-09-13 21:45:55.151]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2023-09-13 21:45:55.151]Killed by external signal
.
23/09/13 21:45:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 3.0 (TID 47) (sparkde.camp.300123.internal executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1694638458719_0001_01_000004 on host: sparkde.camp.300123.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-09-13 21:45:55.150]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-09-13 21:45:55.151]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2023-09-13 21:45:55.151]Killed by external signal
.
23/09/13 21:45:55 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 3 for reason Container from a bad node: container_1694638458719_0001_01_000004 on host: sparkde.camp.300123.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2023-09-13 21:45:55.150]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2023-09-13 21:45:55.151]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2023-09-13 21:45:55.151]Killed by external signal
```

**I notice the stages keep on progressing and eventually it stopped and gave the error as seen**:

```
[Stage 3:=======================================>                 (13 + 1) / 19]

23/09/13 21:54:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 58) (sparkde.camp.300123.internal executor 6): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
23/09/13 22:03:05 WARN SparkContext: Executor 1 might already have stopped and can not request thread dump from it.
```

** This is the screenshot from the spark job**

[image: spark job details]

**Please Help**

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You say your plan is to read from HDFS? But you've shown code reading from Kafka? In any case exit code 143 means a SIGTERM signal forcibly stopped your app. Not a timeout.. Maybe YARN preemption is enabled?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes you are right, I forgot to remove the kafka from the submit job, also I was able to fix the issue, turns out I was always out of memory as the memory size allocated for my YARN was very small in comparison with the kind of job I wanted to perform and I also needed to update the RAM size of my Virtual memory

Answer (score 1):

So I needed to increase the memory allocated to my YARN, so I needed to update the property values in my **yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>21000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>15048</value>
    </property>
```

** So I just updated the values, earlier I was running with just 1GB :) **

Then after some time I still got the same error but this time it was from my VM, I needed to allocate more RAM as my configuration was on 1VCPU and 8GB RAM

So my spark submit job now looks like this:

```
spark = SparkSession. \
    builder. \
    config('spark.ui.port', '4040'). \
    config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', f'/user/{username}/warehouse'). \
    config("spark.executor.memory", "10g"). \
    config("spark.driver.memory", "10g"). \
    enableHiveSupport(). \
    appName(f'{username} | Python - Incremental Loads using Spark Structurd Streaming'). \
    master('yarn'). \
    getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I still think 10g of memory for a driver is excessive. Same for the executor - That would also mean you're limited to at most 2 10g executors on any NodeManager with 21g of total memory. (Kafka consumers do not take near that much heap space)

Comment: I know, I just wanted to go overboard so there wont be any excuse for them not working :) , I would be sure to reduce them as I progress.. Thanks a lot @OneCricketeer

Comment: Also @OneCricketeer, Thankfully everything works but I noticed that when I run the command ` activity_df = spark. \
    readStream. \
    format('json'). \
    option('cleanSource', 'delete'). \
    load(f'/user/{username}/file_df/streaming/activity_df') ` The files get read quite alright but they dont get deleted as expected. I am using Spark 3.3.3, any idea why.. I have checked multiple articles for help

Comment: I'm not familiar with that option. There is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68076627/2308683